# How to fix .htaccess mod_rewrite server error on localhost

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

**Context**

I have a website where users can create articles. I'm trying to use mod_rewrite to make my links include the title of the article for SEO purposes. To start, though, I'm just trying to get the ID of the article and users in the rewritten URL because that's how I access the article. I'm new to regular expressions and editing file configuration in general, so I've been trying to understand what's going on with these mod_rewrite lines. I'm still left failing to understand why the code doesn't work.

**Problem**

I have a URL on my localhost, `localhost/Real%20Website/readArticles.php?article_id=86&userid=64`.

I want to change this to `localhost/Real%Website/readArticles/86/64`.

To do so, I added the following code to my .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f

RewriteRule ^readArticles/([0-9+])/([0-9]+) readArticles.php?article_id=$1&userid=$2 [NC, L]
```

With this code, I get the following error:

```
Server error!
The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request. Either the server is overloaded or there was an error in a CGI script.

If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.

Error 500
localhost
Apache/2.4.46 (Unix) OpenSSL/1.1.1h PHP/7.4.12 mod_perl/2.0.11 Perl/v5.32.0
```

I'm unsure what the problem is here. Is it because I have to account for the `Real Website` folder?

**Question**

How do I fix this server error with the code given above?

Let me know if there are any questions.

Comment: `[NC, L]` has extra space, it should be `[NC,L]`

Comment: Indeed what @anubhava points out will lead to such a result. I would like to additionally remark that what you posted as error message is only what the http server hands out to _others_ , not the full message. This has security reasons, certainly you do not want your internal issues exposed to others. You _always_ need to take a look into the error log file your http server writes. That is where you can learn details about the actual issue which is vital information you need to solve such issues.

Comment: @arkascha Good point, I've never thought to check error logs on my local server for some reason. I'll do this from now on. Thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @arkascha pointed out, [NC, L] has an extra space; it should be [NC,L]. This fixed the issue.